# How to map key values using lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do following:

1] compare each element in list a with b and map similar values.

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
b=[4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10]
```

I tried following:

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
>>> set([9,4,5,7])
```

2] I want these mapped values in same numbering order as appear in list b, such as 4,5,7,9.

3] and lastly I want to use these key values (4,5,7,9) and generate corresponding values from list a, such as:

```
4 (1,2)
5 (3,6)
7 (4,5)
9 (7,8)
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciative?

Comment: I would also like feedback of why negative vote to improve my questions in future.

Comment: A better title might help.  "How to compare lists" is very broad and vague.  `a == b`--there, I compared two lists ;)

Comment: I think people are reacting to the fact that you didn't show any code… except that you did show your solution to part 1, it's just so trivial that it's only one line and people may not have noticed it. Anyway, whether my guess is right or not, it would _definitely_ help if you gave some idea of what thoughts you had, what code you had tried, etc. for the other two parts.

Comment: @Iguananaut: That's a good point; I expected this question to be asking how to compare lists element-wise to get a list of -1/0/1 values or a list of bools, and my fingers were all prepared to type "have you looked at NumPy" before I finished reading the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've updated your question, I see that what you really want is just a map of keys to values:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
b = [4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10]

r = dict([(x, []) for x in b])

for k, v in zip(b, a):
    r[k] += [v,]
```

Here's how to use the results:

```
>>> for k, v in r.items():
...     print k, v
... 
9 [7, 8]
10 [9,]
4 [1, 2]
5 [3, 6]
7 [4, 5]
>>> 
>>> print r[4]
[1, 2]
```

Here's an optimized version that will work faster with less memory usage:

```
from itertools import izip
from collections import defaultdict
r = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in izip(b, a):
    r[k] += [v]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as I need. Just one trivial thing, use of following gives syntax error:
`r = dict([k, tuple() for k in b])`

Comment: I've updated the answer. The first version is plain with no imports and then the optimized version below.

Comment: Using a `defaultdict(list)` with either `append` or `+= [v]` is both conceptually cleaner and a lot more efficient. But otherwise, mapping directly between the two lists with `zip` instead of mapping from one to an index (as my answer does) is a nice simplification. It may be less flexible, but it does exactly what he wants in more obvious code, so if he doesn't need the flexibility, why pay for it?

Comment: You're right, I have no idea why I picked `tuple` haha. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem `3`, you will need to compare each *list* against the opposing set. And that will solve your #2 automatically.

There are other ways to solve #2, like using an OrderedSet (like the [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) linked to in the [`collections` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)), but since they won't solve #3, there's no point getting into that.

---

If the `a` values are very large, you might want to build an index structure—a dict that maps values to collections of indices—to make this faster. Like this:

```
rev_a = collections.defaultdict(list)
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    rev_a[value].append(index)
```

And then the lookup part becomes even easier, and faster:

```
for b_value in b:
    a_indices = rev_a[b_value]
    if a_indices:
        a_str = ','.join(map(str, a_indices))
        print('{} is associated with ({})'.format(b_value, a_str))
```

Or, if you want to create some kind of structure instead of printing out on the fly:

```
results = [(b_value, rev_a[b_value]) for b_value in b]
results = OrderedDict((b_value, rev_a[b_value]) for b_value in b)
# etc.
```

---

That doesn't actually produce the output you asked for, but… I'm not sure what the output you asked for is supposed to come from. Unless you're taking the matching indices from the other list, then looking them up in the first list? That's… odd to say the least. At any rate, an index structure like this should make it trivial to implement any rule you come up with, even a much odder one, as long as you can explain it.

For example, replace the `a_str` line with this:

```
a_str = ','.join(str(a[a_index] for index in a_indices))
```

… and you get your desired output.

Comment: error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: @Ibe: Sorry, that was left over from the original version. See the edit. And +1 for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> a=[1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
>>> b=[4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10]
>>> [x for x in a if x in b]
[4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: This solves the part he already knows how to solve (part 1) less efficiently than his existing solution, and doesn't solve part 3 at all.

Comment: His existing solution doesn't solve the problem. It doesn't have to be fore efficient. If you were concerned about efficiency you would be using an `OrderedDict`. Try running your code through `timeit` sometime.

Comment: `set(a) & set(b)` solves part of his problem, but not his whole problem. Your answer also solves part of his problem, but not his whole problem, and it's less obvious and slower to boot, and you don't give any indication or explanation of why you think it's better. And I have no idea what the second and third sentences of your comment are even supposed to mean, especially since I _did_ use `OrderedDict` in my answer…

Comment: @MattWilliamson You could point out that `set(a).intersection(b)` would be better as `b` doesn't need to be converted to a set before hand...